# how to get the entire url in php including the # symbol with values

Tags: php, html, url

> abcd.com/indexreadmore.php?#cat2

This is what the url in which I want to get all the parts like above mentioned, I can get a bit but not able to get the `#cat2` and help me fetch entire url in php from the url bar.

Comment: For the sake of brevity, it's called a [*"fragment" identifier*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hashtags are not sent to the server, only the browser so PHP wouldn't be able to parse that from the address. You'd have to use javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert(window.location.hash);</script>
```

Comment: I can get the url after # but getting trouble during the comparison of  urls like the same.so help me how to compare the urls like mentioned above. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, what do you mean by compare, what are you trying to compare with? Did you want the full URL using javascript? If so try: alert(window.location.href);

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have stored a url in a variable,I need to compare the current url with the stored url in php.Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot get the URL after the `#` in PHP..

The maximum you can attain is `abcd.com/indexreadmore.php` , To verify this you could just do a `print_r($_SERVER);` on your PHP code.

The content after the `#` can be retrieved only through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to parse the url, then there is [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

```
var_dump(parse_url('abcd.com/indexreadmore.php?#cat2'));
```

The browser does not send the hash fragment to the server if you mean get it in `indexreadmore.php`.